# Rspec controller test - should_receive on instance of model returns 0 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, functional-testing

I'm having an issue with Rails 4.0.3 and rspec 2.14.1 in testing a controller.

The relevant portion of the controller is:

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
  def sign_in
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    # ... - a few other codepaths but nothing that looks for primary_phone
    if params[:email]
      @user.send_token
      flash[:notice] = "blah blah"
    end
  end
```

User.rb is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def send_token
    raise 'Tried to send token to contact with no phone number' if primary_phone.nil?
    SMSSender.sms(primary_phone,"Your login code is: #{generate_token}")
  end
end
```

The spec is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe LoginsController do
  it "sends a token if a valid email is provided" do
    @u = create(:user, primary_phone: "abc")
    User.any_instance.should receive(:send_token)
    post 'sign_in', email: @u.email
  end
end
```

And, my user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "MyString"
    email "a@b.com"
  end
end
```

When I change the spec's `@u = create` line to `@u = create(:user)` (ie, omitting the `primary_phone`), I get:

```
 Failure/Error: post 'sign_in', email: @u.email
 RuntimeError:
   Tried to send token to contact with no phone number
 # ./app/models/user.rb:16:in `send_token'
 # ./app/controllers/logins_controller.rb:19:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/controllers/logins_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is as expected. When I change it back to include the `primary_phone`, I get:

```
  1) LoginsController sign_in sends a token if a valid email is provided
     Failure/Error: User.any_instance.should receive(:send_token)
       (#<RSpec::Mocks::AnyInstance::Recorder:0x007ff537ed4bd8>).send_token(any args)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/controllers/logins_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Having trouble understanding why that change would prevent the spec from passing. I did attach a debugger right after the 'post' in the spec and looked at the flash to see if it was correct (i.e., to ensure the proper code tree in the controller was being run) and it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you need to say `should_receive` rather than `should receive`. This is because of the `any_instance`. `User.any_instance.should receive` means that whatever object `any_instance` returns (an `RSpec::Mocks::AnyInstance::Recorder`) should receive the call. Of course that's not what you want, because that object is *also* not the same instance as what the controller instantiates. (In fact it's not even a `User`.) So the `Recorder` has a special `should_receive` method that does what you actually want. Tricky!

Answer (score 2):

The `User` object you've created in your spec is not the same `User` object that the `sign_in` method creates and sends `send_token` to, so the expectations you set on `@u` as reflected in your error message are not going to be met. They both are associated with the same underlying database record, but they are different Ruby objects. (Note: In the first version of your question, the code you showed for your spec didn't match the error you showed, as the code showed setting an expectation on `User.any_instance` whereas your error message reflected setting an expectation on `@u`

Further, the expectations need to be set *prior* to the call you are expecting (e.g. prior to the `post` in your case, as noted in the comment by @PaulAJungwirth.

Finally, as an alternative to the answer provided by @PaulAJungwirth, you can use:

```
expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:send_token)
```

to address the problem with the your stated expectation line.

Comment: That's reasonable - but what is the way to test this functionality, then?

Comment: You could mock the `User.find_by_email` method, checking arguments if you wish, and return your instance. Or you could set an expectation on any instance of `User`. Those are a couple of options.

Comment: Using `expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:send_token)` gives me: `Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
       Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: send_token`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even notice that you used `expect_any_instance_of` to begin with. My answer obviously doesn't apply. I'll delete it in a few minutes after you read this and edit/undelete if/when I come up with something.

Comment: I think `User.any_instance.should receive` needs to come *before* the `post`, right? You have to set up the stubbed method before you run the code that exercises it.

Comment: @PaulAJungwirth No difference... I had tried that before posting, actually, probably should've mentioned it.

Comment: @PaulAJungwirth is right. Did you get the exact same error when you placed it before the post? Also, your error message in the question shows `@u.should_receive`, which doesn't match the code you posted (and may have been what tripped me up to begin with). I'd suggest updating your question with the expectation properly set prior to the `post` and with the actual error message you received.

Comment: Are you sure you're making it to LoginsController#sign_in? Maybe you have a misconfigured route or a before_filter that is stopping the request. Maybe your test works and your code is broken. :-)

Comment: Oh my, sorry about that @PeterAlfvin! That was sloppy of me. I've updated the OQ with the 'most recent' code and error. Flipping the order of the 'post' and the 'User.any_instance...' lines gives the same error.